# ssh -vvvT git@github.com is sometimes stuck on debug1: Connecting to github.com port 22

Tags: git, github, ssh

When I try to connect to github via ssh it is **sometimes** stuck on `debug1: Connecting to github.com port 22.` The same happens when I try to `git push` to github. The thing is sometimes I get a connection, but very rarely. Maybe out of 30 tries I get through once.

I tried different ports, no improvement. I checked git config, seems fine.

My .ssh/config

```
Host *
  AddKeysToAgent yes
  UseKeychain yes
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

My etc/ssh/config

```
# lots of uncommented lines... then line 48:    
Host *
  SendEnv LANG LC_*
```

Output of `ssh -vvvT git@github.com`

```
OpenSSH_7.9p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/alucca/.ssh/config
debug1: /Users/alucca/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for *
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 48: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to github.com port 22.
```

Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: Sounds like you have a bad SSH client.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you cannot use HTTP URL, you can try and see if [using Using SSH over the HTTPS port](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/using-ssh-over-the-https-port) is a possible workaround for your case.

```
ssh -T -p 443 git@ssh.github.com
```

If that works, you could add to your `~/.ssh/config`

```
Host github.com
  Hostname ssh.github.com
  Port 443
```

Comment: Thank you, but same issue as before: I sometimes get a connection and the next time it's stuck at `debug1: Connecting to ssh.github.com port 443.`

Comment: @Tococorocko Does cloning a GitHub repository using an HTTPS URL work?

Comment: @Tococorocko Also are you on Windows (which has its own OpenSSH, as in https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/issues/1334)?

Comment: i.e. `git clone https://github.com/username/anyrepo.git` worked fine. And I'm on a Mac.

Answer (score 0):

### Problem

I had the exact same error in my case: running `ssh -T git@github.com` got stuck on:

```
debug1: Connecting to github.com port 22.
```

I thought perhaps it could be a bug in OpenSSH, but I had another machine with the same macOS version and OpenSSH and didn't have the problem.

---

### Cause

I was using Little Snitch, which for some reason had blocked SSH traffic to github.com. I went into Little Snitch and enabled it.

- Unfortunately, even though Little Snitch was on alert mode, it didn't alert me about this, and just blocked it.

Here's a similar screenshot for gitlab.com. I had to fix it for gitlab.com as well.

---

### Solution

click the tick mark in Little Snitch, as shown in the screenshot.
[image]